# About Typescript and index

Tags: typescript

I have a serious question about how to use index properly in TS, this for some time. For example...

```
setup.battle.enemies.forEach(enemy => {
        const _thisMove = enemy.movements.random();

        enemy.curMovement = {
            name    : _thisMove.name,
            damage  : _thisMove.elemental.damage(),
            element : _thisMove.elemental.element,
            setMove() {
                const _resistances = variables().player.resistances;

                let _enemyDamage = Math.round(this.damage - _resistances[this.element]);
            }
        }
    })
```

In this case, *_resistances[this.element]* returns this error... *Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ physical: number; fire: number; ice: number; energy: number; water: number; light: number; darkness: number; }'.ts(7053)*

And the resistances obj at the enemies class...

```
this.resistances = {
        physical : 2,
        fire : 0,
        ice : 0,
        energy : 0,
        water : 0,
        light : -2,
        darkness : 0
 };
```

So I would like to ask, how can I make this work properly?

The element property is part of the enemies skills array.

```
this.movements = [
         {
                  name      : "Knife attack",
                  elemental : {
                        element : "physical",
                        damage : () => random(2, 4),
                        getElem : function() { return this.element }
                  }
         }
  ]
```

Comment: Give types to everything (it is *Type*Script after all). Of what type is `this.element`? Currently, it's `any`, but that's not going to work, as the error tells you. It needs to be (ideally) `key of resistances` or `"physical"|"fire"|"ice"|...` or `string`. Ideally, `resistances` would be a type itself; either an `interface` or an anonymous type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use an index for `resistances` you need to declare an interface with an index like this and define `resistances` using it:

```js
interface Resistances {
  physical : number,
  fire : number,
  ice : number,
  energy : number,
  water : number,
  light : number,
  darkness : number,
  [index: string]: number;
}
const resistances: Resistances = {
        physical : 2,
        fire : 0,
        ice : 0,
        energy : 0,
        water : 0,
        light : -2,
        darkness : 0
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is in this.element, this property belongs to the objects of the enemies' skill array. I edited the main post and added that.

Comment: Can you try my solution first? If it doesn't work we can think further

Comment: That worked! Thank you, I'm still taking TS experience.